# Generic method accepting any subclass of java.util.Collection

Tags: java, generics

The interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> {

  void write(Collection<T> items);

}
```

The implementation:

```
@Override
public void write(List<SomeObjectType> items) {
  //...
}
```

The implementation does not compile. I wish to make it so that I can pass either `Set` or `List` to the `write` method.

How can I achieve this with generics? If I cannot do this, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: How have you declared your implementation class?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make it so you can pass either a `Set` or a `List` to the `write` method, then you should be writing

```
class ImplClass implements IMyInterface<SomeObjectType> {
   @Override public void write(Collection<SomeObjectType> collection) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Your interface looks correct, but if you want to be able to pass in any kind of collection to `write`, then `write` needs to take a `Collection`, not just a `List`.

Comment: Thanks Louis, is there a way to also enforce so that only a subclass of `Collection` is accepted? For the interface, I have tried with `<? extends Collection<T>>` but I couldn't get it to work. Essentially only accept `Set` or `List`, but not `Collection` itself

Comment: @czxhlong No, that's not a thing you can do.